# No route matches [GET] "/stories/7/like"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been searching for a little while on this small problem and now just figured I should ask for a helping hand. I am receiving the current error "No route matches [GET] "/stories/7/like"" when i click on a link. Here is my routes.rb since it seems this would be were the problem lies:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users

resources :stories do
member do
put :like, to:'stories#upvote'
put :dislike, to:'stories#downvote'
end
end 

root 'stories#index'
end
```

My Stories_controller is:

```
class StoriesController <ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :upvote, :downvote]

def index
@stories = Story.all
end

def new
@story = Story.new
end

def create
@story = Story.new(story_params)
@story.user = current_user
if @story.save
redirect_to @story
else
Flash[:danger] = @story.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
render new
end
end

def show
@story = Story.find(params[:id])
end

def upvote
@story = Story.find(params[:id])
@story.upvote_by(current_user)
redirect_to :back 
end

def downvote
@story = Story.find(params[:id])
@story.downvote_by(current_user)
redirect_to :back 
end


private

def story_params
params.require(:story).permit(:body)
end

end
```

This is the code for the buttons to work:

```
<%= link_to "That scared me", like_story_path(story), method: :put, class: "btn btn-warning btn-xs" %><span class="text-warning"> (<%= story.get_upvotes.size %>)</span>
    <%= link_to "You Wimp!", dislike_story_path(story), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs" %><span class="text-warning"> (<%= story.get_downvotes.size %>)</span>
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem'devise'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'bootswatch-rails'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
 gem 'byebug'
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
 gem 'spring'
end
```

anything else you need please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your rails version?

Comment: I am using rails 4.2.2, I am using Cloud 9 if that makes any difference

Comment: Can you make sure you have included jquery ujs?

Comment: What's the HTML that it puts in the page?

Comment: I just included my Gemfile as well. i have jquery-rails

Comment: nitecoder, i am trying to code a button that will either add a +1 or another button for a -1

Comment: @PBukuras You should make likes nested inside stories by making a new likes controller and in routes doing the required change. That is the correct way to handle nested routes in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the console in your browser, most likely you have a javascript error which is preventing `jquery_ujs` from intercepting the click event.

`jquery_ujs` listens for click events on links with the `data-method` property and creates a form and posts it to the server. This form contains a hidden `_method` input which Rack picks up on and changes the HTTP Method of the request before it is passed to Rails.

If you have for example a syntax error or reference error which prevents `jquery_ujs` from functioning clicking the link will issue a GET request just like any other link on the interwebs.

All this is because browsers will only send GET requests when you click a link and POST/GET for forms.

Another alternative is use:

```
<%= button_to like_story_path(story), method: :put, class: "btn btn-warning btn-xs" do %>
That scared me <span class="text-warning"> (<%= story.get_upvotes.size %>)</span>
<% end %>
```

> **`button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)`**
>
> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL
>   created by the set of options. This is the safest method to ensure
>   links that cause changes to your data are not triggered by search bots
>   or accelerators. If the HTML button does not work with your layout,
>   you can also consider using the link_to method with the :method
>   modifier as described in the link_to documentation.
>
> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

It's generally the same as above but since you actually explicitly create the form it does not rely on javascript.

Comment: Thank you @max. Being so new I dont think I can appreciate the full amount of information you provided. I am reading more and more so hopefully I will fully get it soon. I also put the (<%= story.get_upvotes.size %>) after end to make it separate. Now the only question I have is, is there anyway to have the page render at the same location you are currently at when you click the like or dislike button instead of reloading you back to the top of the page?

Comment: You can use the 'remote: true' option to send the request asyncrously (as an ajax request).

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you just check if you include the following in your applicaiton.js under jquery?

//= require jquery_ujs

2. Is your browser is up to dated?
   Can you inspect that link and see if you are getting `data-method='put'` inside your anchor?
3. Can you try using data: {method: :put} to see if that is working in your case?

These 3 condition should give you a solution.

Comment: I do have the //=require jquery_ujs. as far as i know my browser is up to date. Being so new, how do i inspect the link to see if i am getting that inside my anchor? Here is some of the error from my server: Started GET "/stories/6/like" for 96.252.66.43 at 2015-10-24 01:56:59 +0000
Cannot render console from 96.252.66.43! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stories/6/like"):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/mid

Comment: go to your browser right click in your link and click on inspect element.

Comment: I also tried putting brackets around method: :put which did not affect the error.

Comment: here is what highlighted: <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/stories/7/like">That scared me</a>

Comment: is it happening when you click on that link right? can you post your application server log?

Comment: where you did run rails s

Comment: yes when i click on the link, I get sent to the error page stating No route matches [GET]

Comment: I have restarted my server multiple times. I have run rake:routes just incase i missed something

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here bud:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :stories do
   match :vote, action: :vote, via: [:put, :destroy], as: :vote #-> url.com/stories/:id/vote
end
```

This is slightly different than your implementation, but much simpler:

```
#app/controllers/stories_controller.rb
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
   def vote
      @story = Story.find params[:id]

      method = request.delete? "downvote" : "upvote"
      @story.send("#{method}_by", current_user)

      redirect_do :back
   end
end
```

This will handle it all in a single action, with the ability to call the `up/down` vote depending on the `method` you send:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", stories_vote_path(@story), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "Downvote", stories_vote_path(@story), method: :delete %>
```

---

The above is the crux of your problem -- you're sending a `GET` request when you don't have that method defining a route.

> No route matches [GET] “/stories/7/like”

The problem here is that you're trying to access a `put` route with a `get` request. Whilst this may be an innocent problem, you *have* to set the `method` in your `link_to` if you want to send any other method other than `get`.

`Max`'s answer explains this particularly well.